# Real SBT Classpath at Runtime

Tags: scala, sbt, classpath

I have some test cases that need to look at the classpath to extract the paths of some files/directories in there. This works fine in the IDE.

The problem is that, when running SBT test, `Properties.javaClassPath` gives me `/usr/share/sbt-launcher-packaging/bin/sbt-launch.jar`.

The classpath is fine when I run `show test:dependency-classpath`. Is there a way to obtain that information from inside the running Scala/Java program? Or is there a way to toss it into a system property or environment variable?

Answer (score 2):

By default the tests are run inside of the SBT process, so the classpath will look like it did when you started sbt (I guess sbt does some trixery to dynamicly load the classes for the tests, not sure). One way to do what you want is to run your tests in a forked jvm, that way sbt will start a new jvm to run the test suite and that should have the expected class path:

```
fork in Test := true
```

Comment: I already had that setting in place. However, I made it a global setting (I'm using subprojects) and I can confirm that the outcome is the same.

Comment: I just tried it with a simple dummy sbt project and it definitively works as expected, are you sure that your tests were running forked?

Comment: This is weird. Is there a way to validate that? It is supposed to be a global setting across all subprojects...

Comment: You could check it with the subproject path as a part, something like ```subprojectA/test:fork```

Comment: It shows as true, and yet it was running showing only the sbt launcher jar in the system property...

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on understanding how the EmbeddedCassandra works in the spark-cassandra-connector project which uses the classpath to start up and control a Cassandra instance.  Here is a line from their configuration that gets the correct classpath.

`(compile in IntegrationTest) <<= (compile in Test, compile in IntegrationTest) map { (_, c) => c }`

The entire source can be found here: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/project/Settings.scala

Information on the `<<=` operator can be found here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings.html#computing-a-value-based-on-other-keys-values.  I'm aware that this is not the current version of sbt, but the definition still holds.