# When running tests from "sbt test" the classpath is different than when running from IDEA

Tags: scala, sbt, classpath, scalatest

I have the following simple test:

```
class ClasspathTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  "The classpath" should "have more than one member" in {
    System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(":").length should be > 1
  }
}
```

This resides in an sbt project. When running this from IDEA, this test succeeds because it contains all the `libraryDependencies` I specified in `build.sbt`.

However, when doing `sbt test` it fails because it only contains `/opt/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar`.

Now I have a test which *depends* on this runtime classpath being fully populated.

Is it possible to populate it somehow?

Comment: My test needs config file from "conf" directory. I had `Runtime / unmanagedClasspath += baseDirectory.value / "conf"` in build.sbt. In this case the test succeeds when I run it in IDEA but fails with `sbt test` command. So I've added `Test / unmanagedClasspath += <...>` line to build.sbt and the issue has gone now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Real SBT Classpath at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557119/real-sbt-classpath-at-runtime)

To make it work, I have to include in my build.sbt:

```
fork in Test := true
```